# Overlay violin plots ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to plot two series of ten violin plots one over the second :

```
library(ggplot2)
#generate some data

coco1<-rnorm(10000,0,1)
coco2<-c(runif(10000))
decile<-rbinom(10000,9,1/2)+1
coconut<-data.frame(coco1,coco2,decile)

#draw the violin plots of the coco1 serie
p <- ggplot(coconut, aes(factor(decile), coco1))
p<-p + geom_violin(aes(alpha=0.3,colour="#1268FF"))
p

#draw the violin plots of the coco2 serie
q <- ggplot(coconut, aes(factor(decile), coco2))
q<-q + geom_violin(aes(alpha=0.3,colour="#3268FF"))
q
```

I would like to plot the violin plot "p" and "q", on the same graph, and I want each violin plot of "q" to be over the corresponding violin plot of "p".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just add the `geom_violin` of the second plot to your first one:

```
p <- ggplot(coconut, aes(factor(decile), coco1))
p <- p + geom_violin(aes(colour = "#1268FF"), alpha = 0.3)
q <- p + geom_violin(aes(y = coco2, colour = "#3268FF"), alpha = 0.3)
```

Now, `q` contains both versions of the violins.
[image]

By the way: If you want to get rid of the colour legend, you have to specify the `colour` outside of `aes`.

Comment: Nice example (+1), a frequent way to do this is to reflect one of the groups distributions, as the density is symmetric. I give an example of doing that here in the comments, http://mbjoseph.github.io/blog/2013/06/24/violin/. One might want to consider different weighting schemes as well; in this example the blue and the red groups should probably have equal areas, since they have equal sample sizes.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to set `position` to be "identity". This example also uses `tidyr::gather` to move the `data.frame` around a bit to make it easier to plot in `ggplot`.

```
library(ggplot2)

coco1<-rnorm(10000,0,1)
coco2<-c(runif(10000))
decile<-rbinom(10000,9,1/2)+1
coconut<-tidyr::gather(
    data.frame(coco1,coco2,decile),
    name,value,coco1,coco2)

p <- ggplot(coconut)+
    aes(x=factor(decile),y=value,color=name)+
    geom_violin(alpha=0.3,position="identity")
p

ggsave("example_identity.png",p)
```

[image]