# Overlay violin plots in r

Tags: r, dataframe, overlay, violin-plot

I am trying to plot overlaying violin plots by condition within the same variable.

```
Var <- rnorm(100,50)
Cond <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)
df2 <- data.frame(Var,Cond)

ggplot(df2)+
  aes(x=factor(Cond),y=Var, colour = Cond)+
  geom_violin(alpha=0.3,position="identity")+
  coord_flip()
```

So, where do I specify that I want them to overlap? Preferably, I want them to become more lighter when overlapping and darker colour when not so that their differences are clear. Any clues?

Comment: You might check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483074/overlay-violin-plots-ggplot2

Comment: Yes, I've looked at it, but they use two variables and overlap them. I have one variables split into two by another variabler. It's not quite the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want them to have different (flipped) x-values, set `x` to a constant instead of `x = factor(Cond)`. And if you want them filled in, set a `fill` aesthetic.

```
ggplot(df2)+
  aes(x=0,y=Var, colour = Cond, fill = Cond)+
  geom_violin(alpha=0.3,position="identity")+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

`coord_flip` isn't often needed anymore--since version 3.3.0 (released in early 2020) all geoms can point in either direction. I'd recommend simplifying as below for a similar result.

```
df2$Cond = factor(df2$Cond)
ggplot(df2) +
  aes(y = 0, x = Var, colour = Cond, fill = Cond) +
  geom_violin(alpha = 0.3, position = "identity")
```

Comment: Thank you so much good sir. This is really nice work!